# Is there a way to generate a RGB color by inputting R, G, and B values from 0 up to 255 without using the matplotlib module in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, colors, rgb

Is there a way to generate a color based on its RGB values rather than the following snippet? (And preferably with a more compact module than matplotlib)

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import scatter, axis, show
R = float(input('Insert R value: '))
G = float(input('Insert G value: '))
B = float(input('Insert B value: '))

def RGB(R,G,B):
  r = R/255
  g = G/255
  b = B/255
  scatter([0],[0],color=(r, g, b), s=1e6)
  axis('off')
  print('R =', R,'\nG =', G,'\nB =', B)
  show()

RGB(R,G,B)
```

By inserting the values of R=50, G=100, and B=200 the code above will return the following window, which is basically a matplotlib scatter plot with an expanded dot:
[image: Code snippet return]

Matplotlib is a huge module and when I try to generate an executable using Pyinstaller the size of the executable gets really big. That's the reason why I'm asking.

Comment: **What exactly do you mean by** "generate a color"? For example, are you trying to create an image file with a solid-colour image? Pop up a GUI window with a rectangle of that colour? Something else? If you simply mean "have some data in the program that represents the colour" then you have already done that as soon as you have input the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your requirements properly, how about using `pillow` module:

```
from PIL import Image

r = input('Input R value: ')
g = input('Input G value: ')
b = input('Input B value: ')

im = Image.new('RGB', (500, 300), (r, g, b))
im.show()
```

which will display a rectangle window filled with specified color.

Comment: Thank you! It worked properly. It just took one minor adjustment which was converting the input to an integer in order to avoid a TypeError.